# Set DataContext for multiple controls with XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

I have different groups of controls bound to different categories of ViewModel classes.

The ViewModels are

- `MainViewModel`
- `VideoViewModel`
- `AudioViewModel`

---

**Question**

How can I set the `DataContext` with XAML instead of C#?

**1.** I tried adding `DataContext="{Binding VideoViewModel}"` to the `ComboBox` XAML, but it didn't work and the items came up empty.

**2.** I also tried grouping all the `ComboBoxes` of a certain category inside a `UserControl` with the `DataContext`:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding VideoViewModel}">
    <!-- ComboBoxes in here -->
</UserControl>
```

**3.** Also tried setting the `<Window>` `DataContext` to itself `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

---

#### Data Context

I'm currently setting the `DataContext` this way for the different categories of controls:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Main
    this.DataContext =
    tbxInput.DataContext =
    tbxOutput.DataContext =
    cboPreset.DataContext =
    MainViewModel.vm;

    // Video
    cboVideo_Codec.DataContext =
    cboVideo_Quality.DataContext =
    tbxVideo_BitRate.DataContext =
    cboVideo_Scale.DataContext =
    VideoViewModel.vm;

    // Audio
    cboAudio_Codec.DataContext =
    cboAudio_Quality.DataContext =
    tbxAudio_BitRate.DataContext =
    tbxAudio_Volume.DataContext =
    AudioViewModel.vm;
}
```

---

#### XAML ComboBox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboVideo_Quality" 
          DataContext="{Binding VideoViewModel}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Video_Quality_Items}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Video_Quality_SelectedItem}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding Video_Quality_IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="105" 
          Height="22"
          Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

---

#### Video ViewModel Class

```
public class VideoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }


    public VideoViewModel() { }


    public static VideoViewModel _vm = new VideoViewModel();
    public static VideoViewModel vm
    {
        get { return _vm; }
        set
        {
            _vm = value;
        }
    }

    // Items Source
    private List<string> _Video_Quality_Items = new List<string>()
    {
        "High",
        "Medium",
        "Low",
    };
    public List<string> Video_Quality_Items
    {
        get { return _Video_Quality_Items; }
        set
        {
            _Video_Quality_Items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Video_Quality_Items");
        }
    }

    // Selected Item
    private string _Video_Quality_SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public string Video_Quality_SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _Video_Quality_SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_Video_Quality_SelectedItem == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _Video_Quality_SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Video_Quality_SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    // Enabled
    private bool _Video_Quality_IsEnabled;
    public bool Video_Quality_IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _Video_Quality_IsEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (_Video_Quality_IsEnabled == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _Video_Quality_IsEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Video_Quality_IsEnabled");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate an object in xaml:

```
  <Window.DataContext>
      <local:MainWindowViewmodel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
```

And you could do that for your usercontrol viewmodels as well.

It's more usual for any child viewmodels to be instantiated in the window viewmodel. Exposed as public properties and the datacontext of a child viewmodel then bound to that property.

I suggest you google viewmodel first and take a look at some samples.

Comment: There was a few more steps had to do. I used your suggestion in the XAML to bind them. I posted it as an answer if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way, but I was able to bind groups of `ComboBoxes` to different ViewModels.

---

I created one ViewModel to reference them all.

```
public class VM: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    public static MainViewModel MainView { get; set; } = new MainViewModel ();
    public static VideoViewModel VideoView { get; set; } = new VideoViewModel ();
    public static AudioViewModel AudioView { get; set; } = new AudioViewModel ();
}
```

---

I used Andy's suggestion `<local:VM>` in `MainWindow.xaml`.

```
<Window x:Class="MyProgram.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProgram"
        >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:VM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

---

And used a `UserControl` with `DataContext` set to `VideoView`, with `ComboBoxes` inside.

Instead of a `UserControl`, can also just use `VideoView.Your_Property_Name` on each binding.

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding VideoView}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboVideo_Quality" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Video_Quality_Items}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Video_Quality_SelectedItem}"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding Video_Quality_IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="105" 
                  Height="22"
                  Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

        <!-- Other ComboBoxes with DataContext VideoView in here -->

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

---

Then to access one of the properties:

```
VM.VideoView.Video_Codec_SelectedItem = "x264";
VM.VideoView.Video_Quality_SelectedItem = "High";

VM.AudioView.Audio_Codec_SelectedItem = "AAC";
VM.AudioView.Audio_Quality_SelectedItem = "320k";
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have obviously provided good answers, however, the underlying miss of your binding is your first set of DataContext = = = = = to the main view model.

Once you the main form's data context to the MAIN view model, every control there-under is expecting ITS STARTING point as the MAIN view model.  Since the MAIN view model does not have a public property UNDER IT of the video and audio view models, it cant find them to bind do.

If you remove the "this.DataContext =", then there would be no default data context and each control SHOULD be able to be bound as you intended them.

So change

```
this.DataContext =
tbxInput.DataContext =
tbxOutput.DataContext =
cboPreset.DataContext =
MainViewModel.vm;
```

to

```
tbxInput.DataContext =
tbxOutput.DataContext =
cboPreset.DataContext =
MainViewModel.vm;
```

Comment: It actually worked with and without the `this.DataContext`, the reason I used that was to bind the program's Title Bar. But I wanted to move away from setting it with C# in the `MainWindow()`. I posted an answer with the new way I'm using, I set the DataContext in the xaml and `get; set` all the different ViewModels in one ViewModel I named `VM`.